# How do I read a file in java coding

Tags: file, readfile

When I run my programming I get an message stating that "File could not be opened". Not sure as to why.

file:///C:/Users/Essence%20Binion/OneDrive/Desktop/School/APSU/Fall%202022/CSCI%202010/ProgrammingAssignment4/src/main/java/csci2010/programmingassignment4/BinionProgram4.java

Comment: Define "didn't work".  Providing a [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: @StephenNewell I am wanting to real a file that is external to my programming. My question is where would I store that file so that it's read into my programming?

Comment: And you said your attempt didn't work, but provided no details as to why it didn't work.  That's why I asked for a [mcve], and for you to clarify the failure.

Comment: @StephenNewell I have edited my question. Hopes this helps you understand it better.

Comment: That's not a [mcve].  Does that file exist?  What does `loadPlayers` look like?  We need to be able to copy/paste your code *exactly* as provided and run it locally.

Comment: @StephenNewell link provided

Comment: No, everything needs to be on the ticket.  This is explained in the link I provided three times.

Comment: @StephenNewell you asked what loadPlayers look like. That's in the link. My coding isn't short so therefore I sent the link (full coding). Thanks for your help. I'll get it figured out elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use the filereader api.
You can check the details here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html